# Displaying a color according with HSBcolor.Lerp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, hsb

Basically I have a data visualization in Unity which i am using the Lerp function.

> Displaycolor =
>   HSBColor.ToColor((HSBColor.Lerp(HSBColor.FromColor(Maxcolor),HSBColor.FromColor(Mincolor),0.3f)));

I'm using this code to Lerp between my Min and Max Colors according to temperature but that part isn't working yet therefore i placed the 0.3f;

[image]

This is the Color range i'm working with.
If I put the min and max for any other color it works perfectly.
However, when i try to Lerp between Dark blue and Red it gives me purple instead of green.
Anyone knows why is that so?
[image]

It functions properly with green to Red here.

[image]

But blue and red returns this purplish color. Why is that?

Here's the HSBcolor.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public struct HSBColor
{
    public float h;
    public float s;
    public float b;
    public float a;

    public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b, float a)
    {
        this.h = h;
        this.s = s;
        this.b = b;
        this.a = a;
    }


    public HSBColor(Color col,float get)
    {
        HSBColor temp = FromColor(col);
        h = temp.h;
        s = temp.s;
        b = temp.b;
        a = get;
    }





    public HSBColor(float h, float s, float b)
    {
        this.h = h;
        this.s = s;
        this.b = b;
        this.a = 1f;
    }

    public HSBColor(Color col)
    {
        HSBColor temp = FromColor(col);
        h = temp.h;
        s = temp.s;
        b = temp.b;
        a = temp.a;
    }

    public static HSBColor FromColor(Color color)
    {
        HSBColor ret = new HSBColor(0f, 0f, 0f, color.a);

        float r = color.r;
        float g = color.g;
        float b = color.b;

        float max = Mathf.Max(r, Mathf.Max(g, b));

        if (max <= 0)
        {
            return ret;
        }

        float min = Mathf.Min(r, Mathf.Min(g, b));
        float dif = max - min;

        if (max > min)
        {
            if (g == max)
            {
                ret.h = (b - r) / dif * 60f + 120f;
            }
            else if (b == max)
            {
                ret.h = (r - g) / dif * 60f + 240f;
            }
            else if (b > g)
            {
                ret.h = (g - b) / dif * 60f + 360f;
            }
            else
            {
                ret.h = (g - b) / dif * 60f;
            }
            if (ret.h < 0)
            {
                ret.h = ret.h + 360f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ret.h = 0;
        }

        ret.h *= 1f / 360f;
        ret.s = (dif / max) * 1f;
        ret.b = max;

        return ret;
    }

    public static Color ToColor(HSBColor hsbColor)
    {
        float r = hsbColor.b;
        float g = hsbColor.b;
        float b = hsbColor.b;
        if (hsbColor.s != 0)
        {
            float max = hsbColor.b;
            float dif = hsbColor.b * hsbColor.s;
            float min = hsbColor.b - dif;

            float h = hsbColor.h * 360f;

            if (h < 60f)
            {
                r = max;
                g = h * dif / 60f + min;
                b = min;
            }
            else if (h < 120f)
            {
                r = -(h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
                g = max;
                b = min;
            }
            else if (h < 180f)
            {
                r = min;
                g = max;
                b = (h - 120f) * dif / 60f + min;
            }
            else if (h < 240f)
            {
                r = min;
                g = -(h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                b = max;
            }
            else if (h < 300f)
            {
                r = (h - 240f) * dif / 60f + min;
                g = min;
                b = max;
            }
            else if (h <= 360f)
            {
                r = max;
                g = min;
                b = -(h - 360f) * dif / 60 + min;
            }
            else
            {
                r = 0;
                g = 0;
                b = 0;
            }
        }

        return new Color(Mathf.Clamp01(r),Mathf.Clamp01(g),Mathf.Clamp01(b),hsbColor.a);
    }

    public Color ToColor()
    {
        return ToColor(this);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "H:" + h + " S:" + s + " B:" + b;
    }

    public static HSBColor Lerp(HSBColor a, HSBColor b, float t)
    {
        float h,s;

        //check special case black (color.b==0): interpolate neither hue nor saturation!
        //check special case grey (color.s==0): don't interpolate hue!
        if(a.b==0){
            h=b.h;
            s=b.s;
        }else if(b.b==0){
            h=a.h;
            s=a.s;
        }else{
            if(a.s==0){
                h=b.h;
            }else if(b.s==0){
                h=a.h;
            }else{
                // works around bug with LerpAngle
                float angle = Mathf.LerpAngle(a.h * 360f, b.h * 360f, t);
                while (angle < 0f)
                    angle += 360f;
                while (angle > 360f)
                    angle -= 360f;
                h=angle/360f;
            }
            s=Mathf.Lerp(a.s,b.s,t);
        }
        return new HSBColor(h, s, Mathf.Lerp(a.b, b.b, t), Mathf.Lerp(a.a, b.a, t));
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        HSBColor color;

        color = new HSBColor(Color.red);
        Debug.Log("red: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.green);
        Debug.Log("green: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.blue);
        Debug.Log("blue: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.grey);
        Debug.Log("grey: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(Color.white);
        Debug.Log("white: " + color);

        color = new HSBColor(new Color(0.4f, 1f, 0.84f, 1f));
        Debug.Log("0.4, 1f, 0.84: " + color);

        Debug.Log("164,82,84   .... 0.643137f, 0.321568f, 0.329411f  :" + ToColor(new HSBColor(new Color(0.643137f, 0.321568f, 0.329411f))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a image for the color range that you wish to interpolate shown as a rectangle and its tempting to think that one end is distinct from the other but it fact HSB colors are better represented as a circle (so you can more clearly see what's happening)

[image]

The color that lies midway between red and blue is magenta and not green (green actually lies midway between yellow and cyan)

When you got the LerpAngle you did this

```
while (angle < 0f)
  angle += 360f;
while (angle > 360f)
  angle -= 360f;
h=angle/360f;
```

but your range does not have the full 360 degrees color complement. You should have limited the angle values you obtained to be inside the lower and upper color values of your range not the full HSB color spectrum.

In your case roughly between 0 and 240 degrees (and you need to use 0 degrees not 360) because

```
(360 + 240)/2 = 300   whereas   (0 + 240)/2 = 120
```

Comment: Thanks alot for this! Fixed it :D and i understood how HSB colors work better now